# How to hide the menu item created by the theme in WordPress admin panel?

Tags: menus, themes

I installed the flatsome theme and it created a menu in the admin panel. I wanted to hide it because it is redundant to Appearance menu that is already in the dashboard. How will I possibly hide the menu item on the sidebar and on the top bar?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUPDk.png) is an screenshot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to WPSE. Can you please specify it's slug, css classes, etc? We don't even know what we're dealing with if you don't provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

1. As a temporary solution, add below script to the function.php file

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'flatsome-hide', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/flatsome.css', array('flatsome'), '1.0' );
```

Crete a CSS file called "flatsome" inside your CSS directory, or whatever you prefer, make sure you update the name and the path on function.php.
Then inspect the menu class and hide it using display: none

2. The second method, use a filter in fuction.php

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page( $menu_slug );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'your-MENU' );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Answer (score 0):

You should ask support from flatsome .They have a active facebook group https://www.facebook.com/groups/flatsome/ . You should ask your question there.